# Neo4j configure performance properties in embedded Spring-Data application

Tags: neo4j, spring-data

How can I configure properties like `neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory` or `nodeostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory` as described at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-io-examples.html?

I am using the Spring Cineast-Demo-Project.
I guess, I have to configure it in applicationContext.xml, where is also the neo4j store defined:

```
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/data/graph_1000_nodesEdges.db" />
```

Any hint, where I can configure these performance-parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/setup.html#d0e3615), example 2.1.8, it shows how to pass configuration parameters to the neo4j engine.